# Not disposing of a WCF proxy?

Tags: wcf, proxy, wcf-client

I have a WCF service which is a singleton and which manages a collection of proxies to another WCF service which is session-based. The singleton creates a new proxy and passes it some work to do, and the session-based service makes calls back to the singleton service when certain activities complete (pretty much all of the OperationContract methods are one-way). The typical completion path is that the singleton receives an event from a hardware device when the process is complete, and it calls a method on the session-based service which returns the final status, and then disposes of its proxy. When an error situation is encountered and the session-based service can't continue with what it needs to do, I need to make a call back to the singleton to let it know to dispose of the proxy associated with that instance. However, to make the WCF method call back to the singleton, I need to create a proxy back to the singleton. What I'm seeing happen is that the singleton disposes of its proxy as expected, but every time the proxy to the singleton that the session-based service created times out when I try to dispose of it. Since the session ends with that method call and the instance will be disposed of, does it matter if the proxy it created doesn't get properly disposed?

Answer (score 0):

Disposing of a WCF service is not the same as disposing of any other object that implements `IDisposable`. It is ok to dispose of the service when it is in a good state but when a fault occurs the dispose method will throw another exception.
[Some insight is here](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2009/06/26/disposing-a-wcf-proxy.aspx) and perhaps use [the WCFProxyGenerator](http://wcfproxygenerator.codeplex.com/) but I have not tried it

Not sure exactly the problem with the session based service and whether it is different from the WCF service.

My recommendation is not to use a singleton but use Dependency Injection to give the class that uses the WCF service a factory so when it wants the service it can create it. And when a fault occurs it can throw away the old and create a new one. Without seeing some code it is hard to see if this is possible.

Comment: It's actually moot at this point, the whole structure of the interactions between those classes ended up completely changing, and the session-based WCF service was completely eliminated. Changing the Singleton to a per-call service wasn't an option, either; it was setup as a Singleton because it was tied to a C++ class that interfaced with a hardware device that raised events that needed to be handled. For what it's worth, though, I never saw any ill effects from not disposing of the proxy back to the Singleton.